# Ubuntu mongodb connection is OK on server side but can't be accessed remotely

Tags: java, mongodb, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

Trying to get the mongo message:

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native
>   driver port.

so I setup my server with mongodb and all looks good. When I do the followings **from the server** it works (i.e., I get the above message):

```
1. http://localhost:27017
2. http://xxx.xxx.xx.110:27017
```

but when trying to do that from any client - it doesn't work (note that http://xxx.xxx.xx.110 is OK running apache).

What I have on the mongo.conf:

> port = 27017
>
> bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
>
> #auth = true

my firewall.rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Aug 28 16:37:08 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4102:2709470]
 :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2893:394270]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
 :ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug 28 16:37:08 2014
```

I added a small java program to test on the server - it works (CRUD). When I try that from a different computer, I get:

```
Aug 29, 2014 9:58:23 AM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection
WARNING: Exception executing isMaster command on /xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017]          bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:214)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:107)
```

Comment: What happens when you have mongo listen on port 80, does it work then from the outside?

Comment: I changed to to 80 - won't work.

Comment: What client are you using to access remotely, and what is the specific error message you are getting? If the port is open (as it appears to be from your check via http) then you should be able to connect from the `mongo` shell to confirm.

Comment: I'm using just a different computer (different network/IP) and try to do: http://xxx.xxx.xx.110:27017 to get the "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." message.

Comment: Did you work out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by starting mongod with the --httpinterface 
[image]